# how to pass three searching parameters only and one of them is selected from options in for loop using Django as a frame work

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a form that has to pass three searching parameters. These parameters are “post city”, “ post category”, and “post subcategories” respectively.

I am using Django for the backend, so the from is populated using Django variables.

I used for loop to fill out the selection list of “subcategories” from the database. The “post city” is preselected as well as “post category”. Therefore, I put them as hidden inputs. However, there is only one city as well as post category within the for loop but they will be repeated while for loop is iterating over the items but I could not keep them out of for loop because I need for loop to select with category we are in.

I want to pass only three inputs with no repeated input to the search form and I want when the user clicks on the “post subcategories” for all three parameters to be passed.

The question is: how can I let the user click on the “subcategory” as an anchor link and have only three inputs “post city”, “post category”, and “post subcategories” be passed. In addition, how can the form know which selection among the “subcategories” list  is clicked on and selected?

**Note:** I used to pass searching parameters through the URL. This method did not fit my needs for this project. I have to pass them in a post form.

Here is the code I used:

```py
<form id="search_param_comm" method="POST" action="{% url 'list_page' %}" data-action="" name="search_param_cat_1" enctype="multipart/form-data" formnovalidate>
    <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-responsiv table-borderless">
        <tbody>
        {% for item in post_sc_community_first %}
            <tr>
                <td> 
                    <!-- first search para -->
                    <input type="hidden" id="post_city" name="post_city" value="{{post_city}}">
                    <!-- second search para -->
                    <input type="hidden" id="category_name" name="category_name" value="{{item.category_name}}">
                    <!-- third search para -->
                    <input type="hidden" id="category_name" name="item.sub_category_name" value="{{item.sub_category_name}}">

                    <a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('search_param_comm').submit(); return false;">
                    <span class="txt"> {{item.sub_category_name}} </span>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: If you're only going to submit one sub category, then why don't you create multiple forms (so <form> inside the loop instead of outside, i.e. each table row is a form) so that you just submit that one form. Note that whatever element you put in the loop cannot have a fixed "id" attribute, as "id" should be unique for the **entire HTML page**. Make sure you append something to your id's that varies each time you loop. That will be important if you have multiple forms.

Comment: Thank you "dirkgroten" for your appreciated response. I thought of it. However, there are other 6 categories on the page i did not list them and each one of them has its own form. Thus, I do not want to fill the page with 6 forms for each category and about 20 forms for subcategories. It would seem like endless forms. I looks ugly to me.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with multiple forms on a page. Even if there are 50 forms.